How to resolve dependency conflict with different versions of a library (Automapper) in .NET
I am facing a dependency conflict in my .NET (Framework) application involving two different versions of Automapper. A third-party library my project depends on requires an old version of Automapper, which is incompatible with the newer version used in my application. This mismatch causes the third-party library to break.
To work around this issue, I am considering creating a separate mini RestAPI application that serves as a wrapper around the third-party library to isolate the dependency. However, I am wondering if there might be a simpler or more direct solution to handle this version conflict.
Does anyone have suggestions or best practices for managing such dependency conflicts without resorting to building a separate service? Is there a way to make both versions of Automapper coexist in the same application?
.Net Framework 4.8

Use a WHEN in the csproj file : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1197868/conditional-build-to-use-project-reference-or-pack

They gave me a version of lib with more modern version of the dependency, so I've stopped digging :/
thanks anyway!
